# wrong validation on a mvc select tag

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-validate

i am currently having a validation issue concerning 2 .jsp pages and some jQuery validation.

The problem in short: i have a set of select elements on my page. None of the fields is empty. However, when i want to submit the form, the fields are marked as not valid. The jQuery code is in file searchbox.jsp and the actual form is in the file searchform.jsp. 
Searchform is getting included in the searchbox file.

here is the validation code snippet:

```
jQuery("#car-search").validate({
//      onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
    focusInvalid: false,
    focusCleanup: true,
    rules : {
        "pickupLocationName" : {
            required : true,
            fullLocation : true,
            minlength : 3
        },
        "pickupDate" : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 1
        },
        "pickupTimeHours": {
            required: true
        },
        "returnLocationName": {
            required: true,
            fullLocation : true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        "returnDate" : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 1
        },
        "returnTimeHours": {
            required: true
        },
        "driverFirstname": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        "driverLastname": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        "driverBirthdate": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10,
            realDate: true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        "pickupLocationName" : "<spring:message code="car_search.pickup_location.required" />",
        "returnLocationName" : "<spring:message code="car_search.return_location.required" />",
        "pickupDate" : "<spring:message code="car_search.pickup_date.required" />",
        "returnDate" : "<spring:message code="car_search.return_date.required" />",
        "pickupTimeHours": "<spring:message code="car_search.pickup_time.required" />",
        "returnTimeHours": "<spring:message code="car_search.return_time.required" />",
        "driverFirstname": "<spring:message code="car_search.driver_firstname.required"/>",
        "driverLastname": "<spring:message code="car_search.driver_lastname.required"/>",
        "driverBirthdate": "<spring:message code="car_search.driver_birthdate.required"/>"
    },
    showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList) {
        if (!validationMessageIsShown) {
            jQuery(".invalidFormMessage #invalidFormItems").text("");
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            if(this.numberOfInvalids()>0){
                jQuery(".invalidFormMessage").jqmShow();
            }
            validationMessageIsShown = true;
        }
    },
    invalidHandler : function (form, validator) {
        validationMessageIsShown = false;
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        showLoading();
        form.submit();
    },
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo("#invalidFormItems");
    }
});
```

And this snippet is the form:

```
<form:form commandName="carSearchForm" method="post" action="${actionUrl}" id="car-search" cssClass="searchForm">
<fieldset>
    ...
        <div class="blueDottedBorder"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="usaStep step3">
        <h4><spring:message code="car_search.driver_section"/> <span class="normal"><spring:message code="car_search.driver_section_info"/></span></h4>
        <div class="clr">
            <form:label path="driverFirstname" cssClass="big"><spring:message code="car_search.driver_firstname"/></form:label>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${empty adultFirstNames}">
                   <form:input path="driverFirstname" id="driverFirstname"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <form:select path="driverFirstname" id="driverFirstname" >
                        <form:options items="${adultFirstNames}" />
                    </form:select>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </div>
        <div class="clr">
            <form:label path="driverLastname" cssClass="big"><spring:message code="car_search.driver_lastname"/></form:label>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${empty adultLastNames}">
                    <form:input path="driverLastname" id="driverLastname" />
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <form:select path="driverLastname" id="driverLastname" >
                        <form:options items="${adultLastNames}" />
                    </form:select>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </div>
        <div class="clr">
            <form:label path="driverBirthdate" cssClass="big"><spring:message code="car_search.driver_birthdate"/></form:label>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${empty adultBirthdays}">
                    <form:input path="driverBirthdate" size="10" maxlength="10" cssClass="birthdate" id="driverBirthdate" />
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <form:select path="driverBirthdate" items="${adultBirthdays}" id="driverBirthdate" >
                        <form:options items="${adultBirthdays}" />
                    </form:select>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </div>
        <div class="info-msg" style="padding-left: 30px; margin-top: 30px;" id="extraPointCost"><spring:message code="car_search.warning_surcharge" /> <a href="<url:car-rental_drop-off-cost />" target="_blank" class="more"><spring:message code="car_search.warning_surcharge.link_label" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px;"><a href="<url:car-rental_conditions />" target="_blank" class="more"><spring:message code="car_search.rental_conditions.link_label" /></a></div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="<spring:message code="car_search.submit"/> &raquo;"/>
</fieldset>
</form:form>
```

I have removed irrelevant fields out of the form. The issue only applies to the driverFirstname, driverLastname and driveBirthdate fields.

In the case that there are no values (so when the inserted lists are empty in the option tags), everything works fine. Validation works normal on the fields who are on that moment regular input fields.

the issue occurs when the lists are not empty, so when there is at least one or multiple options to choose from. As you can see in the form snippet, when there actually are options, the input fields become select fields. it is then that the form does not pass validation, even though the fields are not empty and the value has a size greater then 2.

this really puzzles me. i have been googling for known issues with select fields, i have seen quite some posts here on this forum, but none of the suggested solutions work or would work (i must admit, i havent tried them all as some seem really not fitted for what i want).

any thoughts?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the HTML code that is ultimately rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

It just occurred to me that you may be misinterpreting what the `minlength` rule means when applied to a `select` element.

**Quote OP:**

> ...the input fields become select fields. it is then that the form does
>   not pass validation, even though the fields are not empty and the
>   value has a size greater then 2.

*"size greater than 2"*  ~ Do you mean '*select two items*' or the value contains '*more than two characters*'?

On a `select` list, the `minlength: 2` rule means that the user *must select two items* from the list.  If this is not what you want, then you cannot use this particular rule on a `select` list.  Otherwise, read original posting below the line...

---

You have not shown your HTML as it's ultimately rendered in the browser, so I have no idea how the `select` list is being constructed, if the `value` attributes on the `option` elements make any sense, or if its `name` attribute matches your rule.

This is a working demo/example showing how you would validate a `select` list with the `multiple` attribute.  Pay attention to the HTML of the `select` and its child `option` elements.  Notice how the `value` attributes are filled in, where the first `option` contains `value=""`.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/seUre/**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <select multiple="multiple" name="field1">
        <option value="">please choose</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" name="field2">
        <option value="">please choose</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
        <option value="5">five</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your other options,
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                minlength: "please choose at least {0} items"
            },
            field2: {
                minlength: "please choose at least {0} items"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**EDIT**:

And with your `onfocusout: false,` option set, there are no validation messages until *after* you first click the submit button:  http://jsfiddle.net/seUre/1/

Comment: Hello Sparky! Thank you for your answer! I was under the impression that the "minlength:2" rule meant: have at least 2 characters. So i removed the "minlength:2" rule and everything works fine :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ocket-san, I'm glad it worked out for you.  Yes, `minlength: 2` means at least two characters when it's applied to a `text` field.  When applied to radios, checkboxes, or selects, it means something else entirely.  Please don't forget to 'accept' my answer by clicking the green checkmark.